# How to extend gsm buffer?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

Haii All,
I am using gsm SIM900A module with arduino uno. I am trying to send some data from that to server. When i am writing some commands for that, let's say i have written 3 commands before. But when i am adding one more command, it is giving me error. It seems like there's a buffer issue i.e, maybe it is getting full. So it is nto taking extra commands written on sim900A. How to solve this problem? If it a buffer issue then how should i solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not described the problem .... you only described what causes the problem

Comment: What error do you get? Do you receive an error code from the SIM900A? Or do you have some compiler error? You have to include the full error message and what triggered it into your question

Comment: I got the solution. My SIM900A buffer was getting full. I had to clear it after one complete cycle so that when next time loop will get started, the buffer will be empty to store new data. Thanks for your time. Thank you everyone.